# LWC Jest test can't set @api array/object

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-jest

I have and array @api property and can't set it in test. It also doesnt work if I'm trying to pass object data and works if i pass just string. When I pass array or object it displays in lwc as [] or {}.

```javascript
@api fields;
```

test

```javascript
const element = createElement('c-records', {
    is: records,
});
element.fields= ['1','2'];

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: We'd need to see the component controller as well to figure out what's going on. There's nothing obviously wrong with what you're doing here.